# Python: Conditional combination of data from two json files into one csv file

Tags: python-2.7, file, combinations

I am trying to combine two different files that has different number of records. The first 150 records should be omitted from each file and next 400 records from each file should be combined into a single file. With my limited knowledge of python, the program that I have written is going to infinite loop. The input files are in json format while the output file will be in csv. Below is what I have tried along with the sample data input files.

```
import math
import json

#Acc code begin
fp=open("sitting.csv","w")
activity="sitting"
count=0
while count<650:
   with open("acc.json") as data_file:

      my_list1 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]

   for acce in my_list1:
       Xaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataX']),'.4f'))
       Yaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataY']),'.4f'))
       Zaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataZ']),'.4f'))


       #Gyro code
   with open("gyro.json") as data_file2:

      my_list2 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file2]

   for gyro in my_list2:
       pitch=float(format(float(gyro['dataX']),'.4f'))
       roll=float(format(float(gyro['dataY']),'.4f'))
       yaw=float(format(float(gyro['dataZ']),'.4f'))

# Start writing total 400 records in file starting from 150 records onwards        
if count>150:
   print activity,",",Xaxis,",",Yaxis,",",Zaxis,",",pitch,",",roll,",",yaw
   print>>fp,activity,",",Xaxis,",",Yaxis,",",Zaxis,",",pitch,",",roll,",",yaw

count=count+1
fp.close()
print "Combined File Created"
```

My actual input datasets acc.json and gyro.json

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kKez7DCVT-jL5NT3qlP_Xj8xm1oGq0x5/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zgExiiiDaLP1Hoa0wRGOfvljUQHj6Jko/view?usp=sharing

Please help and also suggest if it is possible to reduce the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not positive about your intent and each step you had done, but I tried to simplify and address the major concerns. First, the indentation meant count wan't getting incremented inside the while loop. Second, things that were supposed to happen once needed to come out of the while loop. Also, I used slice to get rid of unneeded parts of the line arrays. But I think you wanted to get 3 items from each array for each record, so I could not use a for loop for the printing. also the printing needed to happen inside the loop. Also, the online compiler I was using wanted parentheses around arguments to print. Let me know if this needs tweaking, but if I understand you right, it should work (assuming you are satisfied with the pieces of yours I did not change).

```
import math
import json

#Acc code begin
fp=open("sitting.csv","w")
activity="sitting"
with open("acc.json") as data_file:
    my_list1 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]
my_list1 = my_list1[150 : 550]
with open("gyro.json") as data_file2:
    my_list2 = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file2]
my_list2 = my_list2[150 : 550]
count = 1
while count <=400:

    acce = my_list1[count]
    Xaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataX']),'.4f'))
    Yaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataY']),'.4f'))
    Zaxis = float(format(float(acce['dataZ']),'.4f'))

    gyro = my_list2[count]
    pitch=float(format(float(gyro['dataX']),'.4f'))
    roll=float(format(float(gyro['dataY']),'.4f'))
    yaw=float(format(float(gyro['dataZ']),'.4f'))

# Start writing total 400 records in file starting from 150 records onwards        
    print (activity,",",Xaxis,",",Yaxis,",",Zaxis,",",pitch,",",roll,",",yaw)
    print>>fp(activity,",",Xaxis,",",Yaxis,",",Zaxis,",",pitch,",",roll,",",yaw)
    count=count+1

fp.close()
print ("Combined File Created")
```

Comment: I'm really not sure if line 151 of the first file and line 151 of the second are supposed to get combined into a single line in the output file. I thought yes, but if no, the code will need to change (actually can be simplified to eliminate the while loop altogether)

Comment: Thanx jeremy, you can use the actual acc.json and gyro.json that I provided in the OP to verify the result. The output csv should have the format like--                sitting, Ax, Ay, Az, Gx, Gy, Gz  in each row

Comment: The acc.json contains 196 records but gyro.json contains 188. So I think the deduction of first (say 50) records should be done after combination not before, because you are right, a one to one correspondence will be lost if we start from middle. So I changed the list to [ :100] in both the cases and ran while from count =0 to count<=99. Now the file is created with 100 records. I am marking your suggestion as answer. I can easily create another list following your approach final_list [10:100] by reading the csv file . Is there any better approach to do it here itself before writing to file ?

Comment: If I understand you right, sure there is. say if count>9: before the line that prints to file and indent that print line one tab further. This would show the skipped lines on screen but not put them in the file. It is possible my 9 is one off from what is desired and should be 10.

Comment: Got the idea, another if statement before file print that will check the number of records read but not printed. Printing the count on screen can ensure that. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for working with the answer. I'm glad I could help.